# Determine "best" winrate between data with different sample sizes

Tags: self-study, inference, ranking

**Setup**

I've a collection of winrates where each winrate represents a particular combination of "power ups" a player can select for a character they play in a game. The numerator represents games won and the denominator represents total games observed for that particular combination, so the sum of all denoms is the total games played for that character.

$$\Biggl [ \frac{35}{76},\frac{13}{27},\frac{5}{11},\frac{4}{7},\frac{0}{6},\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{0}{2} ... ,\frac{0}{1},\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{1} \Biggr ] $$

---

**Question**

How can I determine the "best" winrate given the variation in sample sizes? This is for a full stack web app, so I am looking to create a (relatively) intelligent process to say:

> Yeah, I'm looking over the winrates and the one at index 0 (46%) is your best. I am saying it's your best because, although it doesn't have the highest winrate (index 1 is 48%, index -1 is 100%), it has a more robust sample size **and** it's winrate is not ***that*** much lower.

---

**What is this for?** (added per request)

I'm interested, for my web app, in aggregating & presenting interesting statistics for the characters people can select to show their different efficacies for winning games. This way people could look up the best way to select their "power ups" for a character they choose to play.

Through analogy, imagine if you, a new chess player, wanted to see the best chess openers so you could use them to increase your chance of winning against some opponent. Now this certainly not an ideal way to evaluate chess openings - I'm just using chess because it's ubiquitous. What you could do is go to a website that says: "Sicilian Defense is the best opener as it has an 80% chance of winning games" and then, from that information, use the Sicilian Defense.

---

**My current thinking** (necessary to read to answer the q, but may help)

A possible naive solution I've been considering is just to only evaluate the first X combinations, where X is some arbitrary cutoff to disregard insufficiently sampled observations. For instance, I could:

1. Only evaluate winrates where the games observed for some combination are greater than 20% of all entire observed games. This would make it such that $\frac{35}{76}$ is the only winrate and is by default the "best".
2. Only evaluate the top 3 most observed winrates and select the highest winrate from them. This would produce $\frac{35}{76}, \frac{13}{27}, \frac{5}{11}$ and classify $\frac{13}{27}$ as the "best".

Both solutions seem naive because:

- They both immediately curtail with arbitrary cutoffs so are malicious in seeking the "best" winrate, when maybe, the true "best" winrate is in the disposed data.
- Point 1 requires a similarly shaped distribution for all different characters. Sorry for springing this on now, but if there are over 100 different characters a player can choose from, how can I be guaranteed that the distribution will play nicely with this metric? What if some character's distribution presents uniformly $[\frac{1}{N}, ..., \frac{1}{N}]$ for N observed combinations of "power ups" where $N > 4$? Then no winrate would be selected.
- Point 2 faces a similar issue where it only caters well to a particular shaped distribution. What if some character presents $[\frac{999}{1000}, \frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{1}]$? The "best" would then be $\frac{1}{1}$ or I'd have a "turtles all the way down" issue where I'm stuck with the same issue I'm trying to resolve, just with lower observations.

Comment: so an alternative is to use confidence/credible intervals see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval. rather than using the expected probability you could use a percentile (to be more cautious).

Comment: ideally you could clarify how this win rate gets used/updated [in your question text, not comments] - that way people might even be able to give you the optimal solution.

Comment: @seanv507 Thanks. I'm a layman to what CIs are, but I'll read through them. I'll also update the question to provide greater context for it's usage/purpose.