Computing heuristic from winrate and number of games
I need to sort big sets of players (of a MOBA) based on their performance represented by their - number of - games and their winrate on these games.
I reduced the initial set of players based on their winrate using simple thresholds but there are still too many players so I need to find the elite of the elite by eliminating the "lucky" players (the ones that have good winrates but not enough games to prove that they were the main factors that contributed to the victory.
I don't want to use thresholds anymore at this stage because I feel like since there are now fewer players in my list, their sorting should now be relevant in order to find the elite of the elite.
Here is a real sample to illustrate the kind of data I'm working on :

I tried $winrate\times \text{log}(games)$ but even though it worked for extreme values (successfully placed (38, 92) at the top but placed way too lower (50, 83).
Intuitively I would say the heuristic I'm looking for tell that best players in the previous example are (38, 92), (50, 83), (18, 95)... I think you see the pattern.
Speaking of pattern, I also tried to rank them myself to be able to draw "regression" lines for each "level" of performance, but in the end I got even more confuse because I end up having a rather very problem-specific solution because it fits this specific set of data points and I don't know how to generalize it.
I'm not working in this field so I'm not used to that kind of stuff and thus cannot find a solution myself, but I think I can manage understanding it at least, so you if you have any reference to known techniques for such scenarios, I would be very grateful.

What are the axes in this plot?  What do the individual points represent?  What do you mean by "performance," given that it appears to be neither the number of games nor the win rate?  What do you mean by "factors that contributed to victory," since you haven't named any such factors?  What is the "computing heuristic" referenced in the title?

Number of games are plotted on the x-axis and corresponding win ratio are plotted on the y-axis. Each point then represents a players's number of games and their corresponding winrate. I should talk about performance as the winrate solely could represent a raw "performance" but I want to take in consideration the number of games because a player that maintain 90% winrate in 40 games is more likely to better than a player with 95% winrate in 10 games.

When talking about factors I wasn't refering to any additionnal variables, it was just a way to say that I'm looking for some score that would highlights good players were the sample was important, but without simply "keeping" points where games is greater than some threshold. That score is the heuristic I mentionned in the title.

How is it possible for all players to have win rates exceeding 60 (presumably a percent of total)? // You would be better off plotting your data rather than a derived quantity like win rate, because the number of games (clearly) matters.

This is already a sub sample that accounts for the players with the best winrates, it represents the elite of players based on winrate solely. I'm now trying to sort "elite within elite" by using not only the winrate but also how many games the player waa able to maintain it over. 92% winrate over 40 games is more "impressive" than 100% winrate ever 10 games.

So you really have to define how you will use this ranking in order for people to give you a proper answer. (please can you add your description of eg axes to main question)

related question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630018/determine-best-winrate-between-data-with-different-sample-sizes#comment1175726_630018 (so far no answers)

@whuber would stein's paradox be relevant here: we are interested in a ranking of the players, for this the mean square error of all the win rate estimates would be appropriate, therefore we should use a shrinkage estimator (even for equal sample sizes)

@seanv507 That's an interesting idea; and the short answer is I don't know.

a simple thing you can do is to use a Jeffreys prior and select a given percentile lower bound. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval Jeffrey's interval.
eg you decide you will rank by the 25% lower bound of the win rate, rather than the expected win rate.
eg in comparing 1 win and 2 losses vs 10 wins and 20 losses
on eg google sheets
=Beta.inv(percentile,wins+0.5,losses+0.5)
=Beta.inv(0.25,1+0.5,2+0.5) = 13%
=Beta.inv(0.25,10+0.5,20+0.5) = 28%
so this percentile combines information about the win rate and the number of games.  Which percentile (25%, 45% etc) you choose is up to you.
adding 1/2 to the wins & losses corresponds to your prior belief without seeing any games of a given player that they have a 50% win rate.  If you have a different typical value (eg you know the average after a single game is 30%, then you could add 0.3, 0.7 to the wins/losses instead of 0.5, 0.5
Another simple (related) thing you can do is called additive smoothing.  Calculate the average win rate (ie total wins of all users)/(total games of all users),$w$.
set $\text{smoothed win_rate}_i = \frac{\text{wins_i} + \alpha w}{\text{games_i} +\alpha}$.
The idea is that $\alpha$ is a pseudo count, so that your estimate is between the raw win rate and the average win_rate - the fewer games player $i$ played, the more their smoothed win_rate is pulled towards the average win_rate.
You could choose $\alpha$ by crossvalidation: eg split your data set 70%/30% into a training set and a validation set. calculate the smoothed win rates on the training set (for different alphas), and calculate how close these are to the raw win rates of the validation set (eg mean squared error). Choose $\alpha$ with lowest error, now recalculate the smooth win rates with all the data and your selected $\alpha$
